# Getting part of autocomplete

Tags: fish

While I typing Fish shows me the autocomplete suggestions, there's any way to accept only part of it suggestion?

For example, I type:

```
$ git
```

So fish suggest to me:

```
$ git push origin master
```

But I'd like send a push to dev branch and not master. For do this, I accept it suggestion and type dev. There's any shortcut to accept part of suggestion?

```
$ git push origin
```

*ALT + Right Arrow* can accept the first word suggested, there's any shortcut for accept all until the last world?

Comment: Faho answered your question but I thought I would point out that I've found it pretty painless to just use [ctrl-E] or [right-arrow] to accept the entire auto-suggestion then press [ctrl-W] to erase the last word followed by whatever I need this time. Alternatively, I've added this binding, `bind \cf forward-bigword forward-word`, so I can just press [ctrl-F] to accept the words from the suggestion I want then type the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ALT + Right Arrow can accept the first word suggested, there's any shortcut for accept all until the last world?

No.

Fish's bindings accept the part of the suggestion they move the cursor over - e.g. "forward-word" would move over the next word if that was actually in the commandline, so it accepts the next word of the suggestion.

The exception is "forward-char" (bound to e.g. right-arrow and ctrl-f by default), which accepts the entire suggestion.

There currently is no binding to accept everything but the last word of the suggestion.

This can be simulated by binding "accept-autosuggestion" and "backward-kill-bigword" (or similar).

```
bind \cf accept-autosuggestion backward-kill-bigword
```